# Is it possible to load Swagger annotations from a different class or file?

Tags: php, annotations, swagger

I have the following simple PHP method like the following

```
/**
*
* (swagger annotation to be called from a different class)
*
*/
public function getApiCall()
{
  //Do something
}
```

and I need to include long Swagger documentation into the annotation above the method, so
**is it possible to write the annotation in a different class ?** and call it here with something like

```
/**
*
*call('App\Http\Controllers\testAnnotation');
*/
```

The main purpose is to have a clean class without so many lines of documentation and annotations in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loading "annotations from a different class" is not something that makes a lot of sense. Annotations are read in the annotated code, that's their whole purpose.

But if you want to keep configuration and code separated, you do not **have** to use [Swagger-Php](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php) to generate your swagger configuration file.

The package is simply a convenience way to generate the `swagger.json` file from code annotations.

But if you *do not want to use annotations in the first place, and keep your classes clean from extraneous configuration* (something that I personally applaud), just... do not use Swagger-Php and build your own configuration files outside of your classes.

You could even write it in YAML, if you feel more comfortable than writing JSON by hand. For example::

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: 'Search API'
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
- url: 
  description: Current host server
- url: https:your-server.com
  description: Prod server
paths:
  /foo:
    post:
      summary: 'Creates a new foo'
      description: 'Builds a new Foo and makes it available to Bar'
      requestBody:
        description: 'Foo '
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Foo created
        '202':
          description: Foo queued, it will be eventually created.
components:
  schemas:
    Foo:
      type: object
      required:
      - name
      - size
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        size:
          type: integer
```

This, once converted to JSON (there are many libraries to do this, or you could even use a free service [like this one](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-xml-csv/cb33a5da)), you can feed the resulting JSON to swagger directly.

E.g. the YAML above parses to [this JSON file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/yivi/517280ff1915bd07b62135d48ff8d00f/raw/8d8e08575a2ec455d409476308497342a6f50f27/swagger.json). You can easily test it out by heading to the [Swagger demo instance](https://petstore.swagger.io/), and past the JSON URL in the "explore" location bar, and you'll get something like this:

> [image]

In the end, it's not much more work than using annotations (if any more work at all), and you can keep your entity classes clean from configuration concerns.

Comment: thats really nice!, but the main reason why, is because i can not feed the resulting JSON to swagger directly for several reasons mainly corporate policies and security aspects, and with using Swagger-Php , i will be able to host the GUI on my domain and access it through {domain}/api/documentation

Comment: You can host Swagger in your domain, of course. The above was just an example. You just download Swagger UI from [here](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/download/), and configure it to use **your** generated JSON as default configuration. That's exactly what Swagger-Php is doing.

Comment: What Swagger-Php does is: convert annotations to JSON, provide a local copy of Swagger UI configured to use that JSON, create a route for you to access that Swagger UI copy. You can do each of these steps on your own, and presto, you no longer need a package or annotations.